# how to navigate to another view when clicked on textview?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitextview

How can I navigate to another view which is a picker view when i click on the `textview`

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use textView Delegate and also make connection form IB to file's owner for textViewDelegate.

use this

```
- (BOOL)textViewShouldBeginEditing:(UITextView *)textView{


  yourSecondView *obj=[[yourSecondView alloc]initWithNibName:@"yourSecondView" bundle:nil];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:obj animated:NO];


[obj release];

}
```